# How To Get Intel Graphics Control Panel In Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, intel

I installed ubuntu on my laptop bt the problem is I am not satisfied with the saturation. So, I want to increase the saturation in ubuntu. So how can I get the Intel Graphics Control Panel For Ubuntu? I use this on windows without any issue and works fine. Thanks In Advance BTW.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly there isn't much to be found. I did find this in Ubuntu Forums:

- [Is there a GUI control panel for Intel graphics?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=870248)

> there's a program called driconf that can tweak some settings for your
>   your videocard.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -y install driconf
> ```
>
> It helped me with regnum and other games with missing textures, I hope
>   it helps you too.

I dug up a screenshot from the [developer's website](https://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/DriConf/):

[image: driconf.png]

If you install the package let us know how it works out.

Comment: Wooow, thanks a lot, this helped me a lot with Skylake chip on my ThinkPad T560. With all these "new" ThinkPads with undervolted CPUs I keep thinking about buying up old Thinkpads, the old T500 models were very good.